# Conversion of a complex number into polar form

Tags: polar-coordinates

Below is the complex number that is to be converted into Polar form.

I'm facing problem in second part of this number(after + mark not the (b) itself).
When I divide them(10/-5+j12) directly, by converting the denominator into polar form and then by dividing the real number 10 with polar equivalent obtained, answer produces incorrectness. 
Though, I know the rules for dividing the complex number, but here if the numerator and denominator both are given in their polar equivalents than how could we determine that we have to take conjugate of denominator because polar equivalents can easily be calculated. How to figure out that?

Any more explanation shall be given if needed.

[image]

Comment: What do you get for the polar form of $-5+j12?$   It should be $13 \angle 112.62^\circ$.  The reason you take the conjugate is to find something that can multiply the denominator and produce a real answer.

Comment: For any complex of the form $a + jb$ you can convert it to polar form $A \ \angle \theta$ where $A = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan \frac{b}{a}$. To go the other way  $A \ \angle \theta = A ( \cos \theta + j \cdot \sin \theta)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider

$$\frac{a + jb}{c + jd}$$

Now we can get rid of the awkward term on the bottom by multiplying $\frac{a + jb}{c + jd}$ by 1. and $\frac{c-jd}{c-jd}$ is 1

$$\frac{a + jb}{c + jd} \cdot \frac{c - jd}{c - jd} = \frac{a \cdot c - j^2b \cdot d + j b \cdot c - j a \cdot d}{c^2 - j^2 d^2} = \frac{a \cdot c + b \cdot d + j(b \cdot c - a \cdot d)}{c^2 +d^2}$$

This works because when you multiply any number by its complex conjugate the result is real.

So you multiply the denominator by its complex conjugate to make it real and you multiply the numerator by the same number so you have in effect multiplied the fraction by 1.

---

To solve your particular example I would first convert $8\angle-20$ to $a+jb$ form because its easier to add complex numbers in this form

$$\begin{align}
\frac{8 \angle -20^o}{(2+j)(3-4j)}+\frac{10}{-5+12j} & = \frac{7.518 - 2.736j}{(2+j)(3-4j)}+\frac{10}{-5+12j}\\
& = \frac{7.518 - 2.736j}{10 - 5j}+\frac{10}{-5+12j}\\
& = \frac{7.518 - 2.736j}{10 - 5j} \cdot \frac{10+5j}{10+5j}+\frac{10}{-5+12j}\cdot \frac{-5 -12j}{-5 -12j}\\
& = \frac{88.86 + 10.23j}{125}+\frac{-50 - 120j}{169}\\
& = 0.415 - 0.628j
\end{align}$$

Which if you want in polar form

$$
0.415 - 0.628j = \sqrt{0.415^2+0.628^2} \angle \arctan \left( \frac{0.628}{0.415} \right) = 0.567 \angle 56.54^o$$

Comment: The information you have provided is quite ok, +1 for your efforts.....,but when we have given a Engg Calculator to solve this then we would readily convert all the numbers from rectangular to polar form without taking care of which number should be multiplied by its conjugate. And if we are given numerator and denominator both in polar form that can be solved with more ease and would have real answer. Now in this situation our process is correct though answers would not match how to get rid of it?

Comment: If you have a calculator that can add, subtract, multiply and divide in either $a + jb$ or polar form you should not need to multiply any number by it's conjugate. Since $a + jb = \sqrt{a^2 + b^4} \angle \arctan \frac{b}{a}$.  Can you provide a specific example where you get different answers.

Comment: That is ok now, I tried it again today. It was me who missed to subtract the polar angle of denominator from polar angle of numerator(as it was 0 so didn't click to me at once). Thanks for your contribution.